# guide to enhance ROR version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

The following environment is:

```
   RubyGems Environment:
      - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
      - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-06-08 patchlevel 173) [x86_64-linux]
      - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/something/ruby/gems
      - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
      - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/something/ruby/gems/bin
      - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
        - ruby
        - x86_64-linux
      - GEM PATHS:
         - /home/soemthing/ruby/gems
      - GEM CONFIGURATION:
         - :update_sources => true
         - :verbose => true
         - :benchmark => false
         - :backtrace => false
         - :bulk_threshold => 1000
         - "gempath" => ["/home/something/ruby/gems"]
         - "gem" => "--remote --gen-rdoc --run-tests"
         - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org/", "http://gems.github.com"]
         - "gemhome" => "/home/something/ruby/gems"
         - "rdoc" => "--inline-source --line-numbers"
      - REMOTE SOURCES:
         - http://rubygems.org/
         - http://gems.github.com
```

**and SUBSTRUCT version:1.3.1**

I need to enhance this version to:
RUBY:  1.9.3
RAILS:  3.2.7
Please guide about the effect I can have on the existing system
Thank you

Comment: My preference to manage ruby/rails/gem versions is RVM (https://rvm.io)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague I believe.

A lot has changed in Ruby 1.9 and we don't know anything about your application. Plus, if you upgrade from Rails 2, you're adding even more potential errors.

You have to test your application against these versions on a dev machine first. Use rbenv or rvm!

For a starter, take a look at this slideshow : http://slideshow.rubyforge.org/ruby19.html#1